# Break line in terminal PS1 fix

Tags: macos, terminal, ps1

I have this code to color my terminal:

```
export PS1="\e[1;30m\][\e[\e[1;30m\]\e[1;33m\] \u@\H \[\e[1;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \e[1;30m\]]\n[\[ \e[1;31m\]\T\[\e[0m\]\e[1;30m\] ] > \e[37m\]"
```

But I have one problem, when text should be in the new line it overwrites the first line.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order for bash to figure out how much screen space your prompt takes up (and therefore where the actual command line starts), you have to enclose the non-printing parts of the prompt in `\[...\]`. Mostly, that means escape sequences like `\e[1;30m` need to be written as `\[\e[1;30m\]`. You have some `\[`'s and `\]`'s in your prompt, but they're in the wrong places, which is making bash very confused. Finding all the printing and non-printing parts of a prompt as complex as yours is not trivial, but I think this gets it right:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;30m[\e[\e[1;30m\e[1;33m\] \u@\H \[\e[1;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \[\e[1;30m\]]\n[ \[\e[1;31m\]\T\[\e[0m\e[1;30m\] ] > \[\e[37m\]'
```

Comment: I had the same problem, thanks for pointing out that you need to have ever non-printing part enclouded in `\[` ... `\]`

Comment: Brilliant - without surrounding the color escape sequences in PS1 with `\[` and `\]` as you state, the cursor position gets out of sync when using up-arrow to select the previous command in the shell history.